# How to wait until vscode.windows.terminal operation is over?

Tags: javascript, testing, visual-studio-code, mocha.js, vscode-extensions

When I execute a testing witch need the ending result of a vscode.windows.terminal the testing gave me a false positive. I need wait until the terminal operation end in order to execute the asserts.

I use a class named Stack witch have a pom file. My test start with the execution of cd  and mvn clean install using the vscode.windows.terminal. The idea of the test assertion is verify the existence of the target file.

```
const buildProgram = () => {
    const terminal = vscode.window.createTerminal();
    terminal.show();
    terminal.sendText('cd ' + stackDirectory);
    terminal.sendText('mvn clean install');
}

    it("Stack Project build taget directory exists", function() {
        const promise = Promise.all([buildProgram()])
        .then(() => {
            return fs.existsSync(stackDirectory + "/target");
        });

        expect(promise).to.eventually.equal(false);
    });
```

This test runs without problem but in the end the target directory is not created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a possible solution replacing the test for this:

```
it("Stack Project build taget directory exists", function() {
    buildProgram();
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(function(){
        // Assert here.
        if(fs.existsSync(stackDirectory + "/target")){
            resolve();  
        }
        reject();
      }, 5000));
}).timeout('7s');
```

I don't really like the idea of using timeout but I don't find a way to say if the terminal is busy.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a function which listens for terminal exit then resolves promise. Essensially we `sendText(yourCommandHere+";exit")` such that the terminal exits after executing your command, and then listen for that exit.

Additionally, I would believe that when sending multiple commands its better to send them on one line, eg: `terminal.sendText(command+";", false); terminal.sendText(command2+";exit")` such that we assure the commands are run in the correct order.

```js
export async function callInInteractiveTerminal(
  command: string,
  shellPath?: string,
  name?: string,
  location?: vscode.TerminalLocation
): Promise<vscode.TerminalExitStatus> {
  const terminal = vscode.window.createTerminal({
    shellPath,
    name,
    location: location ? location : vscode.TerminalLocation.Panel,
  });
  terminal.show();
  terminal.sendText(command, false);
  terminal.sendText("; exit");
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const disposeToken = vscode.window.onDidCloseTerminal(
      async (closedTerminal) => {
        if (closedTerminal === terminal) {
          disposeToken.dispose();
          if (terminal.exitStatus !== undefined) {
            resolve(terminal.exitStatus);
          } else {
            reject("Terminal exited with undefined status");
          }
        }
      }
    );
  });
}
```

After further research it seems this function only works when terminalLocation is TerminalLocation.Panel, not TerminalLocation.Editor.

I'm also a little worried that a fast command might have the exit run before the eventlistener starts, but it works for my use case since i only use it when the terminal needs human interaction.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).